# While JavaScript Loads Page Into Div Display Value?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to achieve is while the `initial load` of the page is taking place is to display a 0 instead of nothing?

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#number_viewers").load('/tools/refresh-viewers.php?page=number')
}, 5000);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="number_viewers" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
```

The problem I'm having is while the `initial load` is taking place it is displaying nothing for example. This is what it is currently displaying `viewers()` while its loading and what I would like it to display while loading is `viewers(0)`. Thankyou for any help.

Comment: Set the value in the div to 0 and then change it using the $( "div.number_viewers" ).text( "your number here" );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is place the 0 into the html first. Then when the load call completes, it will replace the 0 in the number_viewers div.

E.g
HTML

```
<div id="number_viewers" style="display: inline-block;">0</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou didn't realise I could do it like that very useful to know thankyou.